# Setting value of an initialized DataGridViewComboBoxColumnCell in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, selecteditem, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataTable that I am querying data from a database with, and then I am going through each line, and adding a row and applying the values to each row for already existent values. When this line runs

```
DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 1 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield1"))
DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 2 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield2"))
DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 3 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield3"))
```

It sets the .value of the field properly, but it does not set the value on the dropdown, so the value can't be seen. I have a data_error handler, and it is not being fired, so it is not due to the incorrect datatype, and if I select a value from the dropdown, even the value it is supposed to load as, it does change .value and it saves to the database properly, but I can't seem to find a way to set the selecteditem to the value it needs to be.

Full block of code is here:

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If CStr(row("RATETYPE")).ToUpper() = "HEADER" + RateType Then 
                    handleHeaderRow(row)
                ElseIf CStr(row("RATETYPE")).ToUpper() = RateType Then 
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("cuid").Value = CStr(row("cuid"))
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 1 text").Value = CStr(row("keyfield1"))
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 2 text").Value = CStr(row("keyfield2"))
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 3 text").Value = CStr(row("keyfield3"))
                    DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 1 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield1"))
                    DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 2 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield2"))
                    DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 3 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield3"))
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rate 1").Value = CDbl(row("rate1")).ToString("F2")
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rate 2").Value = CDbl(row("rate2")).ToString("F2")
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rate 3").Value = CDbl(row("rate3")).ToString("F2")
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rate 4").Value = CDbl(row("rate4")).ToString("F2")
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rate 5").Value = CDbl(row("rate5")).ToString("F2")
                    i += 1
                End If
            Next row
        End If
```

Comment: How you create `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`?

Comment: @Fabio I created all of the columns manually, those 3 columns happen to be made like this
`Dim cmbkf1 As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With {
            .HeaderText = "Key Field 1",
            .Name = "Key Field 1 cmb",
            .DefaultCellStyle = DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle,
            .ValueType = GetType(String)
            }`

Comment: If the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is set up properly, simply setting the cells value to one of the items in the combo box’s collection is enough to set the combo box cells value. The line you are using for this looks odd… `DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 1 cmb"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CStr(row("keyfield1"))` ? You should be able to simply add the value as you did in the text box… something like… `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Key Field 1 cmb").Value = CStr(row("keyfield1"))`…?

Comment: In addition, it appears you are “duplicating” the value that is in the “Key Field X text” columns to match the “Key Field X cmb” columns… If this is the case, is there some reason you would not simply make the “Key Field X text” columns combo box columns? If you set up those combo box columns properly before you add the data source, then the current values should “automatically” display. There should be no need to “duplicate” the values into another column.

Comment: I am betting, you should loop through the data table and collect all the “distinct” values from the “Key Field X text” column… then use that collection as the data source for that combo box column. Then instead of looping through the `DataTable` as the code does and manually adding the rows. Map the combo columns to the proper `DataTable` columns then add those combo columns to the grid, then simply use the `dataTable` as a data source to the grid. Using this approach, all the posted code becomes unnecessary.